# Delegate bindings from Angular 2 component to nested element

Tags: angular, checkbox, components, custom-controls

These bindings work great:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="foo.bar()" [(ngModel)]="foo.baz">
```

But how do I delegate those bindings to an input *inside* a component?

```
<custom-checkbox>Check me!</custom-checkbox>
```

...and here's the "custom-checkbox.component.html":

```
<span class="checkbox-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> <!-- This should have all the bindings -->
  <span class="checkbox-styling"></span>
  <span class="checkbox-label"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
</span>
```

I've been using Angular 1 for a couple years, but just started using Angular 2 this week.  I've read many articles such as [Custom form controls in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html), Angular docs, other somewhat-similar Stack Overflow questions, and the [TypeScript](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/checkbox/checkbox.ts) used on Angular 2's [Material Checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox) but I still don't get how they pulled this off. It's seems like it should be more straight forward.

This is one of many custom UI elements I need to make, so I'm hoping this example will help me understand the principles and implementation I'm missing.

I know I could use a input checkbox with a selector on it, and wrap it, but I want to be as clean as the [Angular 2 Material checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox) is.

I'm essentially doing the same thing they are (Angular 2 Material), but with our own styling, and much more simplistic than all the options they provide. Just like they said,

> <md-checkbox> provides the same functionality as a native <input type="checkbox"> enhanced with Material Design styling and animations.

and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: put bindings directly on component

Comment: @RomanC If I do that, the model won't apply to the checkbox's truthy state, and I also get this error in the console: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:4:41 caused by: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Angular 1's link function seemed to make this whole process easier, this article seems to give me the guts that Angular 2 Material is using through built-in interfaces with a good example: [Angular 2: Connect your custom control to ngModel with Control Value Accessor.](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel)

This allows the development teams to use my components by binding directly to a component but relaying the bindings to the checkbox (or other form element) inside my template.

Quoting from the site for ease, and for documentation persistence if the link breaks:

> So without further ado, here is our component:

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-input',
    template: `<div class="form-group">
                    <label><ng-content></ng-content>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="value"
                                class="form-control"
                                (blur)="onBlur()" >
                    </label>
                </div>`,
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    //The internal data model
    private innerValue: any = '';

    //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
    //by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    //Set touched on blur
    onBlur() {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

}
```

> We are then able to use this custom control as follows:

```
<form>

    <custom-input name="someValue"
                  [(ngModel)]="dataModel">
          Enter data:
    </custom-input>

</form>
```

---

Thanks Almero Steyn!!

Comment: Would it be possible to use a formControl instead of ngModel? I am asking as you could use formControl.valueChanges as subscription and trigger onChangeCallback.

Comment: @Gambo Unfortunately I have to support ngModels on everything.  But thanks for looking at an alternative.